# Qt 5.3 with Qt png and jpeg support on Buildroot

Tags: qt, buildroot

The default GIF, JPEG and PNG support from QT5 buildroot configuration menu enables support for system libraries i.e. configure parameters are `-system-libjpeg` and `-system-libpng` I want to be able to build Qt with the respective libraries that come bundled with Qt i.e. `-qt-libjpeg` and `-qt-libpng`. I am not able to find a way to pass these parameters to configure, using Buildroot. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Please clarify what you tried so far to solve your problem. Just passing `-qt-libjpeg -qt-libpng` and maybe `-qt-zlib` to `configure` should be enough.

Comment: I am using buildroot. I can not pass the command line arguments to Qt directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, Buildroot's principle is to use the system libraries rather than bundled versions of the libraries, in order to avoid having multiple copies of the same library, be able to update such libraries in the case of security issues, etc.

If despite this you really would like to use the bundled libraries, you just need to change package/qt5/qt5base/qt5base.mk to tell Qt5 to use its bundled jpeg and png libraries.

Comment: Is there any other reason, than maintenance, for not using bundled libraries? I am trying to comprehend what sort of inconveniences might occur

Comment: @Hamzahfrq: Thomas mentions the reasons in his answer: avoid multiple copies, and make sure they are properly updated.

Comment: System (shared) libraries also reduce overall image size.